# SoapUI + sqlite-jdbc = ClassNotFoundException

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, classpath, soapui

I'd like to use SQLite database in SoapUI Groovy script.

I have copied the library *sqlitejdbc-v056.jar* into SoapUI's */bin/ext* directory (theoretically SoapUI classpath) and I use it like this:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
def sql = Sql.newInstance( "jdbc:sqlite:/path_to_database", "org.sqlite.JDBC" )
```

When I run the MockService i get the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:/path_to_database
```

When I use *Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")* i get another exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFOundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

Both methods work fine in groovyConsole.

How can I make them work in SoapUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer.
Apart from copying the library .jar file to *soapui/bin/ext* you need to add:

```
com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver("org.sqlite.JDBC")
```

in your code before using groovy.sql.Sql.